# Qt error: undefined reference to 'QDebug::~QDebug()'

Tags: qt

I am compiling my code with caffe, opencv 3.1 and Qt5.6. Following is my .pro file. I have not included the actual source and header file names here.

```
QT += core gui network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = outsideSituationDetection
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
           mainwindow.cpp \
           <and others>

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        < and others >

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

DEFINES += CPU_ONLY

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -D_REENTRANT -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -pthread
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DQT_COMPILING_QSTRING_COMPAT_CPP -DQT_COMPILING_QIMAGE_COMPAT_CPP

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/lib
DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_imgproc

LIBS += -lm -lglib-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lxml2 -pthread
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/glib-2.0
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/libxml2

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/ \
           /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglog -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl -lnsl
DEPENDPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/


# BOOST Library
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_system
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

#Caffe for CPU System
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../src/caffe/build/include \
           $$PWD/../../../../../src/caffe/include \
           $$PWD/../../../../../src/caffe/build
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../src/caffe/build/lib/ -lcaffe -lglog
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../src/caffe/build
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../src/caffe/build

RESOURCES += icons.qrc
```

Problem - When I compile the code, I get a bunch of 'error: undefined reference to 'QDebug::~QDebug()'' errors along with 'error: undefined reference to `QDebug::putString(QChar const*, unsigned long)'' against all of my .cpp files. (I have successfully built and executed another application without errors using Qt5.6 and Qt5.7.)

```
(.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0):-1: error: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag' File not found (.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0) in main.o
```

What I have tried - Check Qt version to make sure I am using Qt5.6. Deleted the installed qt5-default by doing 'sudo apt-get remove qt5-default'. Downgraded from Qt5.7 to Qt5.6 although it didn't make any difference. I have deleted qt4 and qt5 folders from /usr/include and /usr/share.

Can you please suggest what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple declarations of ' #include "QDebug" ' in files. Removing them and having it in only one file removed the error. (edit- it's incorrect and doesn't work)

What worked - Though I had removed older versions of Qt 3, 4 & 5 , qt was internally using 5.2.1 versions. I do not know where they came from. But when I deleted them all in /usr/lib/x86_linux_gnu/, the code compiled! I also specified the paths to the installed directory explicitly in qtchooser/default.conf. This may not be the best way to do but it worked anyway.

Comment: Really?  The header has include guards, so you should be able to `#include <QDebug>` as many times as you want.  I've just confirmed this on Qt 5.6, with no problems:

#include <QDebug>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << "test";
}

Comment: You are right. It was not the solution. I still have the same problem. Am not sure what I can do.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong, since you're supposed to be able to have multiple Qt versions coexist. You shouldn't need to remove any of them. To use a certain Qt version, you have to create an empty build folder, then invoke **the chosen Qt's `qmake`** on the source, from the build folder. It'll set up the Makefile in the build folder, using chosen Qt. E.g. `mkdir build && cd build && /opt/Qt/5.6.1/bin/qmake ~/src/myproject && gmake -j`

Comment: Thanks for pointing the correct way of doing it to me. I am new to Qt. I did something that made things work in short time but I definitely know that's never a good solution in long term. Thanks again.